# Why I get Run Time Error although I follow the instruction very carefully?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int NoOfDays, years, weeks, days;
    printf ("Please enter the number of days: \n");
    scanf ("%d", NoOfDays);
    years = (NoOfDays)/365;
    weeks = (NoOfDays%365)/7;
    days = (NoOfDays%365)%7;
    printf ("%d = %d years, %d weeks, %d days\n", NoOfDays, years, weeks, days);
}
```

I have tried run the code several time and expecting that years, weeks and days number appears when i enter the number of days; but when i enter the number of days, it just stops for a while, shows nothing and closes the process

Comment: What does your beginners book or tutorial or class say about `scanf` and the arguments it expects? You don't recall seeing an `&` in there somewhere?

Comment: scanf ("%d", &NoOfDays);

Comment: Yeah...this shows a basic misunderstanding of arguments and parameters - they are COPIED.  With such understanding, it would be obvious that scanf() must have address arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In the `scanf` call you need to pass a pointer to `NoOfDays`.

```c
scanf ("%d", &NoOfDays);
```